# how to check whether lzo is working in openvpn

Tags: openvpn, openssl, compression

I have compiled two binaries of openvpn (one with lzo enabled and other without),
Now i want to know whether lzo compression is actually working or not,

1. So I ping from my client to server, but now i don't know how to check size of ping packet on client side and server side, so that i know that lzo compression is happening? how to do it? or is there any other way than using ping for it.
2. I am using openssl with openvpn, so what happens first with data, Lzo compression or openssl encryption?

Answer (score 0):

You can supposedly ask `OpenVPN` itself:

```
$ /usr/sbin/openvpn --help|head -n 1
OpenVPN 2.2.1 i486-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110424-2 (2.2RC2)] built on Dec  1 2014
```